# Unable to use TouchActions to scroll

Tags: java, appium

I was able to use this scroll method I have written using touch actions but now I get a compilation error when I run it. What should I use now or what can I do to fix the compilation issue?

```
public void scrollDown() {

    AndroidDriver androidDriver = ((AndroidDriver)((WebDriverFacade) getDriver()).getProxiedDriver());
    TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(androidDriver);

    Dimension size = androidDriver.manage().window().getSize();
    int startX = size.width / 2;
    int startY = (int) (size.height * 0.60);
    int endY = (int) (size.height * 0.30);
    touchAction.longPress(startX, startY).moveTo(startX, endY).release().perform(); // error on this line pointing to startX and startY within longpress()
}
```

Below is the compilation error

```
method io.appium.java_client.TouchAction.longPress(io.appium.java_client.touch.offset.PointOption) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use following method to swipe screen

```
public void verticalSwipeByPercentages(double startPercentage, double endPercentage, double anchorPercentage, AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int anchor = (int) (size.width * anchorPercentage);
    int startPoint = (int) (size.height * startPercentage);
    int endPoint = (int) (size.height * endPercentage);

    new TouchAction(driver)
            .press(PointOption.point(anchor, startPoint))
            .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(ofSeconds(1)))
            .moveTo(PointOption.point(anchor, endPoint))
            .release().perform();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing Duration parameter

`new TouchAction(driver).press(ElementOption.element(element1))
.waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofSeconds(3))).moveTo(ElementOption.element(element2)).release().perform();`